# Is Teixcalaanli based on a real human language?

Tags: languages, teixcalaan

In Arkady Martine's *A Memory Called Empire* the main planet speaks a language called Teixcalaanli. Is this language based on Aztec, Mayan, or some other real human language?

Comment: According to someone who [reviewed the novel for my website](http://www.freelancetraveller.com/features/reviews/offtable/memcalledemp.html), it's based on Mayan. However, he provided no actual backing for that assertion.

Comment: https://www.npr.org/2019/04/07/710356506/questions-for-arkady-martine-author-of-a-memory-called-empire

Comment: There's also https://www.torforgeblog.com/2020/02/06/whats-in-a-teixcalaanli-name/ which was intended to be linked to from the NPR article, but that link is bad.

Comment: http://languagehat.com/a-memory-called-empire/ notes that "the Teixcalaanli language is reminiscent of Nahuatl (e.g., huitzilahuitlim is from Nahuatl huītzilin ‘hummingbird'", but one example doesn't prove a thesis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up to my comment, I found a [tweet](https://twitter.com/arkadymartine/status/1026888783189422081?lang=en) from the author, Arkady Martine (a pen-name for Dr Anna Linden Weller):

> Teixcalaanli is inspired by Nahuatl (... and Greek); Stationer is
> basically Space Armenian. I’m kinda a language nerd.

So Teixcalaanli is indeed partially based on [Nahautl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahuatl) - a language in the Uto-Aztecan familiy, spoken in Central Mexico.

Comment: I want to read this now just to see what "Space Armenian" looks like!